# Floating Action Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I was trying to create the Floating Action button but I am missing icon.

**My code is:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Lessons of Flutter",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: const Text('Press the button below!')
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.mouse),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**it is a screen from the virtual device.( You can see icon looks weird.)**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use this class, make sure you set **uses-material-design: true** in your project's **pubspec.yaml** file in the flutter section. This ensures that the MaterialIcons font is included in your application. This font is used to display the icons. For example:

[image]

**Refer this link:** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

Answer (score 1):

The Icon is not rendering because of the missing font from the material design library. You have to enable the material design library in your `pubspec.yml` file as given below,

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Just make `uses-material-design` to `true` and the error will be gone. This ensures that the MaterialIcons font is included in your application. This font is used to display the icons Here is the official [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) of `Icon` class